# Is there any encoding that would let me safely write and read any 8 bit char code (the whole 256 not just the 128) to and from a file?

Tags: java, utf-8, compression

I am trying to implement Huffman Tree compression. Pretty much how it works is giving < 8-bit codes to the most common characters in text documents and larger codes to the less common characters. Then there is a binary tree encoded that lets you navigate down with 1's telling you to go left and 0's telling you to go right which leads you to the characters.

So obviously there are chunks that aren't 8 bytes long. I have been rounding them off as need be with 0's at the end and converting them to characters. However, I just found that java writes in 3 bytes per characters. Because this is about compression I obviously want one byte.

The problem is that I don't know what bytes are going to end up trying to be written. Three different < 8-bit codes might get mushed together. I need to be able to write any code to the text file. There are invalid byte sequences however and so my entire approach is all gummed up.

Is there any way that I can let any byte sequence be valid in a certain section of the file and just store it as it literally is and not worry about a character ending the file prematurely or causing another mischief? I am coding on a Mac so that is a problem unlike in windows where they just have the length of the file at the beginning so that they don't need an end of file character.

If there is not a direct solution here then perhaps I could make my own encoding that would not exit the file and nest that inside a more common one?

Comment: If you are trying to read and write binary data (for example, Huffman coded data), you should be using `InputStream`/`OutputStream`, not `Reader`/`Writer`.

Comment: Oh and that will solve my problems because I won't have to worry about what ends up on the documents beyond what the bits themselves certify?

Comment: Correct.   There is no need for the encoded documents to be "readable" in any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use case for Java's Bitset: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

When writing out the data to a file, you should output the number of values which were encoded and afterwards you only need the serialized stream of bits.